# SQL QUERY ISSUE (NOT IN )

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
select NAME  
from Temp_EMP 
where name not in  select NAME from  EMPLOYEE  and deptid ='11'
```

I am getting an error in the statement.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: **STOP YELLING AT US** (we're not the ones causing your troubles...) and give us the **exact error message** you're getting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `WHERE` clause in the subquery:

```
select NAME from Temp_EMP where name not in (select NAME from EMPLOYEE WHERE deptid ='11')
```

Answer (score 1):

Verrigo is close, but I think it should be more like this:

```
select [NAME]
from Temp_EMP
where name not in (
    select [Name]
    from EMPLOYEE
) and deptid = '11'
```

I'm assuming `deptid` is a column on `Temp_EMP`, and that `deptid` is in fact some text field.

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select [NAME] from Temp_EMP where [name] not in (select NAME from EMPLOYEE) and deptid ='11'
```

Or, i think this is a bit more optimized:

```
Select [Name] from temp_emp t left join
employee on e on t.[name]=e.[name]
where e.[name] is null and t.deptid = '11'
```

Comment: Should it not be this logically: 
select [NAME] from Temp_EMP where [name] not in (select NAME from EMPLOYEE) and deptid ='11'